# Merge two XMLs files and only keep what is duplicated using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two XMLs that I would like to match and keep only the information that is on both.

The first one,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <user>
      <User>1</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>2</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2024</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>3</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/8/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>4</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>28/9/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>5</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>15/3/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>6</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>14/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>7</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>24/11/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>8</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/6/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>9</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>26/12/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>10</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>20/2/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
</result>
```

And the second one,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <user>
      <User>1</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/11/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>1</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>2</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2024</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>2</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/12/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>3</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/8/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>3</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>5/7/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>4</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>28/9/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>4</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>24/1/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>5</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>15/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>5</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>10/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>6</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>14/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>6</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>7</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>24/11/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>7</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>27/10/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>8</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/6/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>8</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>17/4/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>9</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>26/12/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>9</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>16/11/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>10</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>13/3/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
      <User>10</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>20/2/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>CSV</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>1</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>1</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/11/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>2</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/1/2023</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>2</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>1/12/2022</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>3</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>5/7/2022</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>3</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/8/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>4</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>24/1/2022</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>4</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>28/9/2020</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>5</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>15/3/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>5</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>10/3/2024</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>6</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/3/2022</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>6</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>14/3/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>7</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>24/11/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>7</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>27/10/2020</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>8</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>9/6/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>8</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>17/4/2020</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>9</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>26/12/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>9</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>16/11/2021</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
   <user>
      <User>10</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>20/2/2025</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
      <User>10</User>
      <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
      <LastModified>13/3/2022</LastModified>
      <Source>SF</Source>
   </user>
</result>
```

I would need to use XSLT to create a new XML that contains the same user and source.

For example,

On the first XML I have User '1' and Source 'SF' so I would need to keep from the second

```
<user>
    <User>1</User>
    <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
    <LastModified>1/1/2025</LastModified>
    <Source>SF</Source>
    <User>1</User>
    <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
    <LastModified>1/11/2021</LastModified>
    <Source>SF</Source>
</user>
```

And remove the ones with source 'CSV'

```
<user>
    <User>1</User>
   <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
   <LastModified>1/11/2023</LastModified>
   <Source>CSV</Source>
   <User>1</User>
   <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
   <LastModified>1/1/2023</LastModified>
   <Source>CSV</Source>
</user>
```

And then on User '2' I have Source 'CSV' so it would be the same but this time remove the ones with 'SF' and keep the 'CSV' ones

Comment: It seems easy in XSLT 2 to group the two documents based on `User` and `Source` and only emit output if a group has two items. That kind of assumes that you don't expect a single input document to already have duplicates on its own, but that doesn't seem to be the case for your sample data. Grouping has been treated here lots of time, and introduction is in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: I'm not experienced on XSLT, would you be able to help?

Comment: It is not quite clear which result you want, the first document seems to have a single data in each `user` element, the second seems to have two or more. You haven't even shown which complete result you want to create nor explained the whole merging for the complete sample. Also, if you are not experienced with XSLT, then perhaps try something you are experienced with or take your time to gain some experience with sample data from tutorials, then try to implement your own requirement, if you really fail after doing some effort show us your best attempt and how it failed.

Comment: The first XML contains information where the last modfieid is the max date. The second one contains all the data for the user and they have different sources being CSV and SF. I need to filter the second one with the data from the first. So that the data remaining on the second XML will be based on the first one. So if I have user 1 and source CSV on the first XML I want to keep both user 1 records with source CSV on the second xml but remove the user 1 records with a SF source